April Fools Origami Update
Me (Sunny Lu) and Ωmega_3301 have made a special April Fools edition of origami puzzles.
The objective is to fold a shape into a rectangle with uniform thickness. The thickness will be given to you.
Shapes that do not have a clearly labeled thickness are not meant to be solved.
There are no restrictions on how many folds you can make, how long each fold can be, where the fold can be, et cetera.
In the first counterexample, the resulting shape is not a rectangle. In the second counterexample, the resulting shape does not have uniform thickness 2, as given by the puzzle.

The bottom are 11 April Fools puzzles. There is no "trick" to the puzzle: you do not need to break any rules to solve them. There is no "bending the rules" or "thinking outside the box" required. There are no "hidden messages" or "hidden puzzles" outside the solutions for the 11 puzzles.
Clearly, all solutions do not have to be feasible, just theoretically possible. Recommended tools for this puzzle are 1. paper, 2. calculator, and 3. online tool for REDACTED. Happy April Fools!

Huge thanks to Ωmega_3301 for coming up with the origami genre and the idea for the April Fools selection.

Downvotes - why?

Maybe because of genre fatigue - you have posted several puzzles of the same nature within a very short window of time (you have been informed about this several times before)? Too much to solve for a single post (could be divided up into smaller chunks)?  It’s a bit harsh still though.

I understand... I didn't want to postpone posting this (for obvious reasons), so I guess I rushed.

I think this an interesting variation. The high thickness numbers make things possible that normally are not. I had to think a long time about some of them. +1 from me.


 They are all possible, as indicated in the picture.
 First simplify with folds on gridlines only.
 Then use the base strategy, except for:
 1: Use the same technique from 2 sides, needed since the requested thickness is low
 8: Also work from 2 sides and use that the requested thickness is an (odd) multiple of 3.
 0: The same strategy does not seem to work, but forming a thickness 5 and 7 square and then working with multiples of 35 is possible due to the high thickness requested.



Nice! Not very elegant, but I don't think there is an elegant solution. This is intended. There's a secret puzzle that I'm not sure you have completely explicitly identified, so I'm not accepting for now. Edit: never mind you mentioned the secret puzzle; I'm blind
